# Allure HTML Report is not generating via TestNG, displaying empty report

Tags: maven, testng, allure

I am trying to create an Allure HTML Report using Maven TestNG. In `pom.xml` I used maven site plugins and ran `mvn site` through the Windows command prompt.

The Allure HTML file is generated, but the report is empty (not showing anything in the Overview).

Test class:

```
@Features("My Feature")
@Stories({"Story1", "Story2"})
public class oauth 
{
    ResponseValidator validator;

    @Test(groups="test",testName = "Oauth",description="Myoauth")

    public void oauth() throws Exception 
    {
--------------------xxyyyx----------
    }
}
```

Here is my pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>api</groupId>
  <artifactId>api</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <properties>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
 </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
      <artifactId>allure-testng-adaptor</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.4</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.13.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
      <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
      <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy-json</artifactId>
      <version>2.4.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>jfree</groupId>
      <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>



  <build>

    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>

                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <groups>test</groups>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</outputDirectory>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                     <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>

                    </configuration>

                    <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                    </plugin>



                    <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>9.2.10.v20150310</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${project.build.directory}/site/allure-maven-plugin</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <stopKey>stop</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>1234</stopPort>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
    </plugins>

  </build>

  <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>ru.yandex.qatools.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                   <dependencyLocationsEnabled>false</dependencyLocationsEnabled>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>



</project>
```

Comment: Are you sure, that report creation needs to be triggered via `mvn site` ? Based on [this](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure1/issues/758#issuecomment-193797610) comment, it looks like you should be using `mvn test`

Comment: Running with mvn test is running only test. Allure html report is not created in site folder. @KrishnanMahadevan from above doc, understand that we need run commands in cmd to invoke html report. But is there any option to create html report using maven pom xml